# spring-session-data-redis not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-session

I've tried the example provided by official reference [Spring Session](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#samples). After login via http://localhost:8080/login it seems session data is still stored in memory, and no redis interactions(observed through `redis-cli monitor` command). Only JSESSIONID stored in cookies

Settings below:

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
            p:hostName="192.168.1.230"
            p:port="6379"
/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="root" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/ping" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:form-login default-target-url="/ping"/>
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="io.hbprotoss.demo.controller"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the session repository filter, like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Since you are using spring security make sure that session repository filter is declared *before* security filter (and any other filter(s) that might want to access the session otherwise you might end up with two session one provided by the servlet container and one by spring session.

More details can be found here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#xml-servlet-container-initialization

Comment: I don't quite understand the usage of filter-name. Does it affect which feature to use provided by filter-class? Since I have two filters with same filter-class but different filter-name now.

Comment: That is what `DelegatingFilterProxy` filter does (check its docs). You actually have the real filters as spring beans. The `springSessionRepositoryFilter` is created because of this line `<beans:bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>`

Comment: Got it. Thanks for help :)